# Max and Min of Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I have some questions about the aggregation function `MAX` and `MIN` in SparkSQL

In SparkSQL, when I use the `MAX` / `MIN` function only `MAX(value)` / `MIN(value)` is returned.
But How about if I also want other corresponding column?

For e.g. Given a dataframe with columns `time`, `value` and `label`, how can I get the `time` with the `MIN(Value)` grouped by `label`?

Thanks.

Comment: do you know how to do this in regular sql? normally you would do something like `ORDER BY value desc LIMIT 1`

Comment: @maxymoo Thanks. Its related to grouping so I prefer using aggregation function.

Comment: @libenn after your edit, actually maxymoo's way might be the easiest. What you want to do won't work since you are using an aggregation function, all the results have to be aggregation function results or columns by which you group by (label in your case).

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Thanks. But how can I group them by label in maxymoo's case ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a first do a `groupBy`, and then `join` that back to the original `DataFrame`. In Scala, it looks like this:

```
df.join(
  df.groupBy($"label").agg(min($"value") as "min_value").withColumnRenamed("label", "min_label"), 
  $"min_label" === $"label" && $"min_value" === $"value"
).drop("min_label").drop("min_value").show
```

I don't use Python, but it would look close to the above.

You can even do `max()` and `min()` in one pass:

```
df.join(
  df.groupBy($"label")
    .agg(min($"value") as "min_value", max($"value") as "max_value")
    .withColumnRenamed("label", "r_label"), 
  $"r_label" === $"label" && ($"min_value" === $"value" || $"max_value" === $"value")
).drop("r_label")
```

Comment: this won't return the `time` column, and that's what the OP wants

Comment: Misread the question. Hold on.

Comment: Edited my answer to actually, you know, answer the question. :)

Comment: @DavidGriffin Thanks! This actually works! But the number of tasks doubled...

Comment: On the other hand it doesn't do an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Also, I can do `min` and `max` in one (well, two apparently) pass. See edits.

Comment: You could even do `avg()` at the same time, if you wanted. 3 for the price of 1.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Not any longer, at least not with default settings. Since 1.6 Spark schedules aggregations on multiple columns separately if not configured otherwise.

Comment: a) How do you configure it otherwise? b) Would you expect it to be faster that way or separately? c) Out of curiosity why was it changed?

Answer (score -1):

You can use sortByKey(true) for sorting by ascending order and then apply action "take(1)" to get Max.

And use sortByKey(false) for sorting by descending order and then apply action "take(1)" to get Min

If you want to use spark-sql way, you can follow the approach explained by @maxymoo