# How to find max and min with single aggregate function in spark RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am a ios developer and now switching into spark. I want to know how I can find Max and Min in Spark RDD with one aggregate function?  (Preferred Spark SQL )
For example- Suppose I have salary column in my csv file and now I want to convert it in to Spark RDD and I want to find Max and min by using single Function and Also How can I load csv file in RDD (Scala preferred).
I do not want to convert it in Data frame. I want to find max and min with single aggregate func and that too in RDD. I so not want to use Max and Min twice.

Comment: can you explain your use case a bit? Also some example code of what you are trying to accomplish will be helpful.

Comment: Suppose I have salary column in my csv file and now I want to convert it in to Spark RDD and I want to find Max and min by using single Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [aggregate function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@aggregate[U](zeroValue:U)(seqOp:(U,T)=%3EU,combOp:(U,U)=%3EU)(implicitevidence$30:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):U) to perform custom aggregation.

Aggregated value should be a custom object that stores both min and max

```
case class MinMax[T](min: T, max: T)
```

it requires 2 functions to combine aggregated results and adding new value to aggregation

```
def comb[T](left: MinMax[T], right: MinMax[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): MinMax[T] = {
  MinMax(min = ordering.min(left.min, right.min), max = ordering.max(left.max, right.max))
}

def seq[T](minMax: MinMax[T], value: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): MinMax[T] = {
  comb(minMax, MinMax(value, value))
}
```

then having those you can aggregate, for example rdd with `Long`

```
val minMax = rdd.aggregate(MinMax(Long.MaxValue, Long.MinValue))((mm, t) => seq(mm, t), (l, r) => comb(l, r))
val min = minMax.min
val max = minMax.max
```

Comment: Is there any way to perform it in Spark SQL?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36051300/187261

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I do have 2 question. Would you mind I mail you? both question is not hard but since I am new to spark so I am facing issues.

Comment: Yes. Although you can create new questions here in StackOverflow and somebody will answer them quicker

Comment: a) Write a Spark Job to read the sales data (emp.csv) and find minimum and maximum salary value using single aggregate() function with spark RDD  b) Write a Spark Job to read sales data (emp.csv) and find employee wise minimum and maximum salary value using single foldByKey() function with spark RDD. (Spark Sql)

Comment: Create new separate questions, this discussion is not for comments

Comment: Apologies I am new to stackoverflow. I have created new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311081/how-to-write-these-jobs.

Answer (score 1):

One of the method to find `Max` and `Min` in `spark scala` is to convert your `RDD` to `dataframe` and find `Min` and `Max` in `aggregation` [more info](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)